# Recursive appox. of sphere in WebGL, vertex position array fetching more points than provided?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, glsl, webgl

I am doing this WebGL exercise where you have to generate a 3D sphere via recursive subdivision of triangles. So far, nothing renders on screen for me besides my buttons and an empty black canvas. The debugger throws a series of warnings that say "WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: Vertex fetch requires 195, but attribs only supply 192.". I have included my HTML and .js code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const vec3 = glMatrix.vec3;
const vec4 = glMatrix.vec4;
const mat4 = glMatrix.mat4;
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

let numTimesToSubdivide = 3;
let index = 0;
let positionsArray = [];

const near = -10;
const far = 10;
const radius = 3.0;
let theta = 0.0;
let phi = 0.0;
const dr = 5.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;

const left = -2.0;
const right = 2.0;
const ytop = 2.0;
const bottom = -2.0;

var modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
var modelViewMatrixLoc, projectionMatrixLoc;

var eye = vec3.create();
const at = vec3.create();
vec3.set(at, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3.create();
vec3.set(up, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

function triangle(a, b, c) {
    positionsArray.push(a);
    positionsArray.push(b);
    positionsArray.push(c);
    index += 3;
}


function divideTriangle(a, b, c, count) {
    if (count > 0) {

        var ab = vec3.create();
        vec3.lerp(ab, a, b, 0.5);
        vec3.normalize(ab, ab);

        var ac = vec3.create();
        vec3.lerp(ac, a, c, 0.5);
        vec3.normalize(ac, ac);

        var bc = vec3.create();
        vec3.lerp(bc, b, c, 0.5);
        vec3.normalize(bc, bc);

        divideTriangle(a, ab, ac, count - 1);
        divideTriangle(ab, b, bc, count - 1);
        divideTriangle(bc, c, ac, count - 1);
        divideTriangle(ab, bc, ac, count - 1);
    } else {
        triangle(a, b, c);
    }
}

function tetrahedron(a, b, c, d, n) {
    divideTriangle(a, b, c, n);
    divideTriangle(d, c, b, n);
    divideTriangle(a, d, b, n);
    divideTriangle(a, c, d, n);
}

gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);
gl.enable(gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
gl.polygonOffset(1.0, 2.0);

var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var vertexShaderSource = `
        attribute vec4 aPosition;
        uniform mat4  uModelViewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix* aPosition;
        }
    `;
gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vertexShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(vertShader);

var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
var fragmentShaderSource = `
        precision mediump float;
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    `;
gl.shaderSource(fragShader, fragmentShaderSource);
gl.compileShader(fragShader);

const shaderProg = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(shaderProg, vertShader);
gl.attachShader(shaderProg, fragShader);
gl.linkProgram(shaderProg);
gl.useProgram(shaderProg);

const va = glMatrix.vec4.create(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1);
const vb = glMatrix.vec4.create(0.0, 0.942809, 0.333333, 1);
const vc = glMatrix.vec4.create(-0.816497, -0.471405, 0.333333, 1);
const vd = glMatrix.vec4.create(0.816497, -0.471405, 0.333333, 1);

tetrahedron(va, vb, vc, vd, numTimesToSubdivide);
console.log("Number of vertices:", positionsArray.length);

const vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positionsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProg, 'aPosition');
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);

gl.vertexAttrib4f(positionLoc + 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.vertexAttrib4f(positionLoc + 2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.vertexAttrib4f(positionLoc + 3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProg, 'modelViewMatrix');
projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProg, 'projectionMatrix');

document.getElementById("Button0").onclick = function () {
    theta += dr;
};
document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function () {
    theta -= dr;
};
document.getElementById("Button2").onclick = function () {
    phi += dr;
};
document.getElementById("Button3").onclick = function () {
    phi -= dr;
};

document.getElementById("Button4").onclick = function () {
    numTimesToSubdivide++;
    index = 0;
    positionsArray = [];
    init();
};

document.getElementById("Button5").onclick = function () {
    if (numTimesToSubdivide) numTimesToSubdivide--;
    index = 0;
    positionsArray = [];
    init();
};
render();


function render(array, offset) {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    vec3.set(eye, ((radius * Math.sin(theta)) * Math.cos(phi)), ((radius * Math.sin(theta)) * Math.sin(phi)), ((radius * Math.cos(theta))));

    modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.lookAt(modelViewMatrix, eye, at, up);

    projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.ortho(projectionMatrix, left, right, bottom, ytop, near, far);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, new Float32Array(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, false, new Float32Array(projectionMatrix));


    for (var i = 0; i < index; i += 3)
        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, i, 3);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

}

render();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sphere</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <button id="Button0">Increase theta</button>
    <button id="Button1">Decrease theta</button>
    <button id="Button2">Increase phi</button>
    <button id="Button3">Decrease phi</button>
    <button id="Button4">Increase subdivisions</button>
    <button id="Button5">Decrease subdivisions</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
    <script src="gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
    <script src="sphere.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its apparent that my vertex position array is providing only enough positions for 64 triangles but drawArrays is expecting enough for 65. This appears to be a off by one error of sorts but I cannot figure out why. With each run of divideTriangle(), I have 3 vectors for splitting each 'leg' of an existing triangle in half and recursively calling triangle() to make more triangles and incrementing the index by 3 so I fail to see how I am mathematically not coming out with enough vertex positions. If I add a debug line and print the length of the position array to the console, it says there are 768 vertex positions which makes even less sense.